# Elastic Beanstalk load balanced did not inherit the parent instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP apps deployed into AWS Elastic Beanstalk using eb init.

At first I use single instance cause the console tell that I can change it in future.

I had my apps set the document_root to /public .

It's working well until I change it into Load Balanced, auto scaling through

AWS Elastic Beanstalk Console page.

If I try to access my environment url, if I directed by Elastic Load Balancing to the parent instances ( the first instances created by Single Instance), my apps will be available, but
when it hit the other instances, I will receive

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I think the other instances are not getting the setting for document_root = /public.

How can I make the others instances clone the parent instances including the configuration ?

Just for info,

Currently I have 2 minimum instances running and will auto scale.

Right now, 1 instance is working and another 1 is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when you change your environment type from "Single Instance" to "Load Balanced", the new instances inherit another EC2 Security Group, which limits port 80 only to load balancer instance.

As mentioned in "[Configuring Elastic Load Balancing with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html)" guide, you need to update EC2 Security Group if you want to access your instances directly from the web browser.

> If you are deploying an application using a nonlegacy container type,
>   and you want to access your application directly on the EC2 instance
>   using your web browser, modify your HTTP rule in your EC2 security
>   group. For instructions, go to [Amazon EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html#using-features.managing.ec2.securitygroups).

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi thanks for your help,

But in my case, I am able to hit the other instances, which means the ELB connect me to the other instances, the error for Forbidden also happen before because I didn't specify my document_root when I use single instance, after changing the configuration to point the document_root to /public as needed by the framework to run, its work.

From my security group, only the ELB and RDS security groups only available.

If ELB is the cause, I think I will not even able to access the EC as its not configured in ELB.

Comment: @bluehyppo23 I'm a little bit confused, when you say "hit other instances", does it mean directly (SSH, HTTP) or through ELB(HTTP)? About "parent" instance: when you change your environment from single instance to load balanced, so called "parent" instance ceased to exist, all the changes made in "parent" will be gone. New EC2 instances are instantiated and your application is deployed on each of them. They will be identical, except `is_leader` flag value. Unless you use a snapshot, which you did not mention, so I assumed you do not.

Comment: Its through the ELB, because I access them using the URL given by Beanstalk. Maybe the correct term is leader instance, from my understanding, in Load Balanced, there must be 1 leader instance right ? and if I access the URL given by Beanstalk, sometimes the apps run, if I open up new browser (incognito mode) if it goes to others instant (not the first instances), it will give the Forbidden Access.

Is there a way to test with 2 min instances in Load Balanced, and test both instances if they are working, cause right now, I am unable to know on which instances the page are served.

Comment: @bluehyppo23 There's no such concept as "leader" in Elastic Load Balancer. Here's how ELB works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584858/aws-elb-doesnt-distribute-requests-to-auto-scaling-group-ec2-instances-in-some/20591793#20591793 The way you describing it, it seems that you have enabled "sticky sessions" in your Elastic Load Balancer configuration. With "incognito mode" the sessions are not present, so ELB will forward the request to a random instance. Connect with ssh to both instances and watch http access log. Also check wget with localhost. Do you have any "leader_only" commands?

Comment: I dont have sticky sessions enabled. I have leader_only commands to run some command that need to be run by one instances only.

Comment: @bluehyppo23 Did you try to ssh to your instances and execute wget on both? You have to isolate the issue, to determine whether you have to reconfigure ELB or something is inconsistent with your instances.